# What does "{optional}" after an attribute mean

Tags: uml, staruml

[image]

Please explain me, what `{optional}` means in ship description.

Is it some value from UML documentation or a mistake?

Comment: Are your sure of {optional} ? I looked to the specification, i did not find it ...

Comment: I too, but I did not find this word on my diagram again.

Comment: Which CASE Tools do you use?

Comment: Maybe (only maybe) it is only a mistake and class designer set the type of attribute to `Ship {optional}`. In this case the diagram shows like yours.

Comment: This is a part of diagram for a test assignment sent by me to the employer for admission to courses, so I do not know what he used to create a chart and whether it was done correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think (!) this is an invention of StarUML (since I suppose you used this tool to create it). UML does not have such a property modifier (see p. 111 of the UML specs for a complete list of valid keywords). Optionality is represented by adding a multiplicity `[0..1]` like this:

[image]

However, I guess everyone could easily recognize the same semantic from that `{optional}` property modifier.

Comment: @granier I fostered the specs and there's nothing in that direction. Where did you see that?

Comment: "A lower bound of zero means the Parameter is optional" section 9.4.3.4. for Feature and Operation inherits of Feature ...

Comment: @granier That's what I say. But that property above does not exist.

Comment: @Kilian i am not sure to understand what you mean by "that property above does not exist" which one ? What i cited is for Feature ... For property, for me, {optional} does not exist in the specification.

Comment: @granier Where did I say  "that property above does not exist"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162363/discussion-between-granier-and-thomas-kilian).

Comment: I looked quickly to OCL specification, since text between parenthesis should be constraint. I did not find anything about a an optional keyword.

Comment: See p. 111 of the specs: property modifiers are also enclosed in curly brackets.

Comment: yes these modifiers may be seen as constraint, the last one is a constraint :  <prop-modifier> ::= ‘readOnly’ | ‘union’ | ‘subsets’ <property-name> | ‘redefines’ <property-name> | ‘ordered’ | ‘unordered’ | ‘unique’ | ‘nonunique’ | ‘seq’ | ‘sequence’ | ‘id’ | <prop-constraint>. But anyway optional is neither defined as constraint in the specification nor in OCL specifiation. Or I miss something, which is possible.